# XAMPP accessed by another computer

Tags: xampp

I need help , I don't know how to edit code in XAMPP so that I can create a server with my ip 
PS. even if I have a dinamic IP my internet company provided me a DNS address name.go.ro 
srry for bad english , please help and thanks

Answer (score 0):

You really need a static IP.
If you config your router to forward a request to your port you are done.

The process is different per router.
I suggest you google port forwarding + your router type or name.

Comment: ok but I still need a little help with XAMPP config that is the main reason of this post, I tried some things but it never worked and I allready port fowrd.

Comment: You dont need to change any xampp settings for this to work. The router configuration is the part that matters. If the port forward is succeeded you can visit your xampp website by calling he internal IP with port xamp is listening too from your local network, Example: 192.168.1.10:81 . you can acces the samen content by visiting your external IP wich you easely can find by visiting sites like www.mijnip.nl for instance.  you need to make sure the ports xamp is listening to are correct and that the router points incoming calls to the IP of the computer running xampp. I hope this makes sense.